# Are there benefits of a clan tag?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I see a lot of people with clan tags online. So, are there any benefits of having one, beside having a clan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clan tag is simply a way through which to distinguish yourself as being part of a specific clan.

Other than aesthetics, a clan tag has no inherent value or benefits in game.

For more information: [Clan Tag-The Call of Duty Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Tag#Call_of_Duty:_Modern_Warfare_3)

Comment: Though an entire team whose names are prefixed with BUTT can strike terror into the hearts of its opponents.

Comment: Join the Church of the Random Weapons Crate today! [CRWC]. WaW fans will know...

Answer (score 0):

No. It only distinguishes you from the rest in terms of your call sign appearance.